# zsh vi mode Esc-k places insertion point at end of line

Tags: zsh, zshrc

When I use vi command mode in bash and hit Esc+k or Ctrl+[ the cursor is placed at the beginning of the line. This is what I prefer.

When I hit hit Esc+k or Ctrl+[ in zsh, the cursor is placed at the end of the line.

How can I make the zsh vi mode act like bash vi mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562292/zsh-history-with-cursor-at-beginning-of-line

For me, these lines provided the fix. Add them to .zshrc and voila.

```
bindkey -v
bindkey -a j vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -a k vi-up-line-or-history
```